# SQL where exists not the same count

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the differences between two tables.

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where exists (select * from table2 as t2
              where t1.field1 = t2.field1 
                and t1.field2 = t2.field2 
                and t1.field3 = t2.field3)
```

This returns 939,234 matches

```
select *
from table2 as t2
where exists (select * from table1 as t1
              where t2.field1 = t1.field1 
                and t2.field2 = t1.field2 
                and t2.field3 = t1.field3)
```

This returns 938,796 matches

Shouldn't I expect both numbers to be the same?

To find the differences in both tables I would just change the `where exists` to `where not exists` right?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Not sure why you do not get the same number of rows.  However, why not trying `select t1.* from tablel t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.field1=t1.field1...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not expect the two queries to return the same number of rows.  Let's consider a much simpler example:

table1:

```
id     val
 1      1
 2      1
```

table2:

```
val
 1
```

This query returns `1`, because one row in `table2` matches:

```
select count(*)
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.val = t2.val);
```

This query returns `2`, because two rows match:

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.val = t2.val);
```

In other words, the tables may have duplicates.  When that table is in the `from` clause, the duplicates are returned as separate rows.  When that table is in the correlated subquery, the duplicates are not counted.

Comment: I didn't think about duplicates... I wrongly assumed uniqueness.

Comment: @Tarik . . . It took me a moment to understand your confusion.  Then I realized that you were thinking "Hey, these are equivalent ways to get the overlap between the tables.  Why are the results different?"  At first, it really did not occur to me why someone would think these would be the same.  After some thought, though, I could see why this would be confusing.  For future reference, duplicates and `NULL` values are often the cause of non-intuitive behavior.